# Fetching MP3-Tags while recording a stream using java

Tags: java, audio, io, streaming, mp3

I currently have this code, which successfully records an (mp3-)stream:

```
public class Recorder {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Recorder(URL stream, File dest) {
        thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                URLConnection connection = stream.openConnection();
                InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();

                OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int length;

                System.out.println("Now recording " + stream.toString());

                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0 && running) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        running = true;
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I read the MP3-tags (song title and artist name) from the stream properly? I've found a few answers on how to fetch the MP3-tags from files, but not from streaming audio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mp3agic library](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic).

> A java library for reading mp3 files and reading / manipulating the ID3 tags (ID3v1 and ID3v2.2 through ID3v2.4).

If your file has ID3 tags you can do:

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("src/test/resources/v1andv23tagswithalbumimage.mp3");

if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
   ID3v1 id3v1Tag = mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
   System.out.println("Track: "   + id3v1Tag.getTrack());
   System.out.println("Artist: "  + id3v1Tag.getArtist());
   System.out.println("Title: "   + id3v1Tag.getTitle());
   System.out.println("Album: "   + id3v1Tag.getAlbum());
   System.out.println("Year: "    + id3v1Tag.getYear());
   System.out.println("Genre: "   + id3v1Tag.getGenre() + " (" + id3v1Tag.getGenreDescription() + ")");
   System.out.println("Comment: " + id3v1Tag.getComment());
}
```

Comment: The feature to read tags from a stream has been [proposed in an issue but not resolved yet](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic/issues/78), so I'm afraid mp3agic won't help me. :/

Comment: What about using a temporary file?